# Concatenate Dictionary List Values while adding a '+' sign between the values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, concatenation

I have a dictionary similar to the following:

```
myDictionary = {'Rent' : ['100'], 'Other Income' : ['10', '45, '20']}
```

I am trying to join the values of the dictionary lists into a single string, while adding a '+' sign between them.  My goal is to have the output look something like this:

```
myDictionary = {'Rent' : ['+100'], 'Other Income' : ['+10+45+20']}
```

I've been searching around for an answer to this for a few days now and can't come up with something that will work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following dict comprehension

```
>>> {key: ['+'+'+'.join(values)] for key, values in myDictionary.items()}
{'Rent': ['+100'], 'Other Income': ['+10+45+20']}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked wonderfully.  I started learning this about a month ago, so I'm still very much a newbie.